# Autocompletetextview Not support hitpac keyboard (Specially in Samsung)

Tags: java, android

I am using Custom adapter for AutoCompleteTextview Suggestion and find very Strange issue that it work fin in any device but when i try in samsung j7 which has " hitpac keyboard " not showing any suggestion but when i change to default samsung keybord it work fine. :-(

```
   objectAdapter=new ObjectAdapter(myclass.this,data);


        mautotextview.setThreshold(1);
        mautotextview.setAdapter(objectAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Found the solution after study Android Documentation of edittext i have to set type of which type of krybord i want to open i just added line `android:imeOptions="actionSearch"` in xml and it worked for me